# Anet E10 - Print above 270 °C or "maxtemp" error

Tags: troubleshooting, hotend, temperature

Hoping to determine the reason for my inability to print over ~270 °C on my Anet E10.

To date all operation has been fine.  Attempting to move to a configuration that supports above 250 °C up to ~300 °C.

The control board is the default V1.5 with no changes purchased ~Aug 2019.

I use OctoPrint to interact with the printer.

When attempting to print with a temperature > 270 °C OctoPrint shows it is stopping with a "maxtemp" error. The same "maxtemp" error occurs if I just set the settings to 270 °C and let is sit there for a couple of minutes at most.

This occurs with or without the bed being heated.

I can print successfully at 260 °C with or without the bed being heated.

I have changed the thermistor to another 100k glass bead and a 100k within a canister. There where no changes in the ~270 °C "maxtemp" stoppage.

I have also changed the heater from what was there (30 W I believe) to two different new 40 W (resistance of about 4.1 Ω) without a change in the ~270 °C "maxtemp" stoppage.

The power supply seems not to be involved here since "maxtemp" stoppage occurs without the bed being heated.

I believe this is solely the reason that the control board has a "maxtemp" set at 275 °C. (but I don't know this since I can't find a statement that the V1.5 has this setting by default).

Is there something I am missing in this scenario?  It seems I need to flash the board with settings that have maxtemp > 275 °C - say for my needs ~300 °C.

---

*Regarding the hotend, I neglected to mention and should have, that I have upgraded it to a Micro Swiss in preparation to print over 250 °C.*

Answer (score 1):

Your firmware has set a limit of 270 °C, normally, (default Marlin configured value) this is 275 °C. It appears that the Anet E10 developers have edited the value if you cannot exceed the 270 °C setpoint.

The configuration file for Marlin firmware has the following maximum temperature limit set for the first hotend:

```
#define HEATER_0_MAXTEMP 275
```

You can change this yourself, but, you need to flash new firmware, making sure that you're using all the correct settings for this printer model.

As a general remark (for others reading this), you shouldn't simply increase the temperature without changing the hotend (unless it is capable of high temperature printing), if the default hotend is lined with a PTFE tube, the PTFE can form dangerous/toxic gasses at elevated temperatures above 270 °C. But, in your case, an all-metal Micro Swiss hotend is installed that doesn't have the PTFE liner.

---

*Note that the Anet E10 configuration can be found in the [Marlin configurations zip file](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/tree/2.0.x/config). For the 2.0.7.2 version, the E10 already has the hotend temperature limit increased to 305 °C.*